# Does the existence of the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ imply that f(x) is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ when f(x) is continuous in this same interval?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, bounds-of-integration

Does the existence of the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ imply that f(x) is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ when f(x) is continuous in this same interval ?

*edit*

I'm trying to use Cauchy without knowing what the next step is, stating that $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ exists if and only if $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_a^xf(x)dx $ exists and approachs a particular value, which means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $t_0$ such that for all $x,y > t_0$ : $$|\int_a^y f(x)dx - \int_a^x f(x)dx | < \epsilon$$
and since $$\int_a^y f(x)dx - \int_a^x f(x)dx = \int_x^y f(x)dx$$ we get that $$|\int_x^y f(x)dx|<\epsilon$$

And from here I don't really know what conclusion can be drawn. Does that mean that f(x) is indeed bounded ? It seems to me that I'm missing some counter-example to disprove the statement.

Regards

Comment: No, try doing triangular bump of height $n$ on the interval $[n,n+\frac{2}{n^3}]$ for every $n \ge 1$

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad Hi, edited

Comment: Just imagine that it's very flat with occasional spikes that grow taller and skinnier, growing skinnier much faster than the grow tall, so that the area of the spikes quickly become small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the existence of the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ imply that f(x) is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ when f(x) is continuous in this same interval ?

No. For each interval $[n,n+1]$ define $f_n:[n,n+1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by piecewise linear extension of the following four points:

$$f_n(n)=0$$
$$f_n(n+\frac{1}{2n^3})=2n$$
$$f_n(n+\frac{1}{n^3})=0$$
$$f_n(n+1)=0$$

So it's a triangle with basis of length $1/n^3$ and height $2n$. And thus

$$\int_n^{n+1}f_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

And for $n=0$ we put $f_0$ to be the constant $0$ and so $\int_0^1 f_0(x)dx=0$.

Now we glue all $f_n$:

$$f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=f_{\lfloor x\rfloor}(x)$$

$f$ is continuous, it is not bounded but

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}f_n(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\sqrt x \sin(x^2)$ is unbounded (check the points $\sqrt {\pi/2+2n\pi}).$ Letting $x=\sqrt y,$ we get

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt x \sin(x^2)\,dx = \int_0^\infty  \frac{\sin(y)}{2y^{1/4}}\,dx .$$

The integral on the right converges, conditionally, by Dirichlet's test.

Here's one that converges absolutely: $\int_0^\infty x[\cos^2x]^{x^5}\ dx.$ I discussed the proof of this here  [Lebesgue integrable and continuous function with divergente sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444014/lebesgue-integrable-and-continuous-function-with-divergente-sequence/1444061#1444061)